# Using Rapid API Google Translate API with React Project

Tags: reactjs

So I am making a React Component that uses the Google Translate API to translate text to different languages using a `FormControl` (Material UI). When I try to connect to the API on `RapidAPI`, I keep getting a 401 error.

Here is my code for connecting the the API and its use in `App.js`

```js
useEffect(() => {
        getLanguageData(text, language)
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
        })
    }, [text, language]);
```

```js
import axios from "axios";

const URL = 'https://google-translate1.p.rapidapi.com/language/translate/v2';

export const getLanguageData = async(text, language) => {
    try {
        // response goes here 
        const data = await axios.post(URL, {
            headers: {
              'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
              'x-rapidapi-host': 'google-translate1.p.rapidapi.com',
              'x-rapidapi-key': '672f444ba1msh5ef96f3113280dep176206jsnb157cac756a8'
            },
            data: {q: text, target: language}
          });

    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: From a quick search it looks like [version 2](https://code.google.com/intl/nl/apis/language/translate/v2/) of the API has been deprecated?

Comment: The only thing in your code I can see would cause an error is that you're not returning anything from `getLanguageData`. After the axios call you should return `data`. Otherwise the rest looks fine

Comment: So I added the return data after the axios call. I still get the 401 error and am not sure why.

Comment: 401 error means your request is not authorized. I would check your auth details and also make sure you DON'T share them publicly